# Calcular frete para mais de um produto no carrinho Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Quando adiciono apenas um produto no carrinho ele mostra as opções de frete que configurei, porém quando tem mais de um produto não tem opção para frete e solicita verificar forma de entrega.
Segue link da loja para simulação:
[loja](https://www.gmeletrica.com/loja)

Como faço para calcular o frete para vários produtos no mesmo carrinho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tente alterar o peso do produto, vi que está usando quilos, troque para gramas.

O produto "Emergência LED 100-240 V – Bivolt( da blumenau)" está com 200 centímetros, realmente é 2 metros?